# How to compute the channel gain from the path loss model of a wireless channel

Tags: signal-analysis, digital-communications, fading-channel

I did my research but I did not get a satisfying answer. 
We have a transmitter and a receiver over a wireless communication channel. The channel's path loss is modeled as 
$ 128 + 37 \log_{10} (d)$, with a shadowing standard deviation of $10$ dBs.

I am assuming that this path loss equation is expressed with dBs (nothing explicitly says that).

I have read that the combined path loss and the shadowing model is just the addition of the path loss model and a normally distributed random variable with mean $0$ and std. $10$ dBs.

- Is this addition of path loss and shadowing is the same as the channel gain ?
- If not, how to calculate the channel gain $\vert h \vert$ from the path loss model, combined with the shadowing ?

Comment: Do you know how to calculate channel gain based on path loss?

Answer (score 3):

To answer the literal questions you asked:

- yes
- see above

To [Frame Challenge](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6843) your question and give you what you were probably looking for:

The path loss equation you cited:
$$
128+37\log_{10}(d) ,
$$
is equivalent to:
$$
\frac{P_r}{P_t} = \frac{10^{-12.8}}{d^{3.7}},
$$
where $P_r$ is the received power in Watts, and $P_t$ is the transmit power in Watts.  From this equation it can be seen that the [path loss exponent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_loss#Loss_exponent) is 3.7.

Under [log-normal shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-distance_path_loss_model#Mathematical_formulation), the random shadowing component is modeled as a zero-mean Gaussian random variable (in dB) added to the path loss.

Answer (score 1):

The answers are

- No.
- You cannot.

Small scale (channel gain) and large scale (path loss + shadowing) fading effects cannot be deduced from each others. They have independent characterizations. The channel gain characteristics must be given. Usually in rich multi-path fading with no line-of-sight (LOS), Rayleigh fading is assumed, while if there is a strong LOS,  Rician fading is assumed.